# Dynamic PIVOT over dynamic and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

i'm trying to pivot dynamic pivot on multiple columns in SQL Server 2012

My table is as below

```
customer UnitNo  invoiceNo  invDate    heads   Amt periodFrmDT  periodToDT  
abc      GF-3    C0000001  2015-11-01 Charge1  100 2015-11-01   2015-11-30  
abc      GF-3    C0000001  2015-11-01 Charge2  500 2015-11-10   2015-12-10  
abc      GF-3    C0000001  2015-11-01 charge3  600 2015-10-01   2015-10-30
```

and i want result like below

```
customer unitNo invoiceNo   invDate    Charge1  PeriodFrmDT periodToDT  Charge2  PeriodFrmDT    periodToDT  Charge3  PeriodFrmDT periodToDT

abc      GF-3   C0000001    2015-11-01  100     2015-11-01  2015-11-30  500      2015-11-10   2015-12-10    600     2015-10-01   2015-10-30
```

i have tried yet

```
 select * from (
    select c.Customer,unitNo, ih.invoiceNo
    ,bh.heads,it.Amt,periodFrmDT,PeriodToDT
    from invHeader ih
                inner join customer c on c.custID =ih.custID
                inner join mstUnit mu on mu.unitID=ih.unitID
                inner join invTran it on it.invID=ih.invHeaderID
                inner join billingHeads bh on bh.BillHeadID=it.headID           
    )P 
    Pivot 
    (
     max(amt)         
     for Head in([charge1],[charge2],[charge3])      
    ) as pvt
```

Please help..

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic - Is it because you don't know what 'Charge1', 'Charge2' and 'Charge3' will actuall say? Also, if you have more than one row for abc, GF-3,  C0000001, 2015-11-01 how do you want Amt, periodfromDT and peroidToDat summarised? Sum Amt? earliest from date, latest to date? And because this is going to need testing, please could you provide code to create your first table, so we don't have to. (ie a declare @table1 table... and insert into @table1)

Comment: Also, you will need to unpivot first.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the table you have specified. The key thing here is that you must unpivot the amount, from date and to date for each charge first. This then allows you to repivot and see the values for all 3.

First I faked your data as follows:

```
declare @cte table (customer nvarchar(4)
        , UnitNo nvarchar(4)
        , invoiceNo nvarchar(8)
        , invDate datetime
        , heads nvarchar(8)
        , Amt int 
        , periodFrmDT datetime
        , periodToDT  datetime)
insert into @cte ( customer, UnitNo,  invoiceNo,  invDate,    heads,   Amt, periodFrmDT,  periodToDT)
values 
('abc',      'GF-3',    'C0000001',  '2015-11-01', 'Charge1',  100, '2015-11-01',   '2015-11-30'), 
('abc',      'GF-3',    'C0000001',  '2015-11-01', 'Charge2',  500, '2015-11-10',   '2015-12-10'),  
('abc',      'GF-3',    'C0000001',  '2015-11-01', 'charge3',  600, '2015-10-01',   '2015-10-30');
```

Then I used the following query to get out the data as you requested:

```
with mycte as (select * from @cte
               )
select * from 
    (
    select customer, UnitNo  ,invoiceNo  ,invDate, heads + '_' + columnname as heads, value 
    from (select customer, UnitNo, invoiceNo, invDate, heads
               , cast(Amt as nvarchar(10)) as Amt
               , left(convert(nvarchar(10), periodFrmDT, 120), 10) as periodFrm
               , left(convert(nvarchar(10), periodToDT, 120), 10)  as periodTo 
          from mycte
          ) as t1
    unpivot(value for columnname in (Amt, periodFrm ,periodTo)) as t2
    ) as t3 -- this table gives you your initial columns, then 2 more with the column headings for the next stage, and the values
            -- columnname contains [Charge1_Amt], [Charge1_periodFrm], [Charge1_periodTo] etc
pivot (min(value) for heads in ( [Charge1_Amt], [Charge1_periodFrm], [Charge1_periodTo]
                               , [Charge2_Amt], [Charge2_periodFrm], [Charge2_periodTo]
                               , [charge3_Amt] , [charge3_periodFrm], [charge3_periodTo]
                               )
       ) as t4 -- And then we can re-pivot it all back up again.
```

To use the second query directly from you data, replace

```
with mycte as (select * from @cte
               )
```

with

```
with mycte as (
    -- This is the query with your base data
    select c.Customer,unitNo, ih.invoiceNo, invDate ,bh.heads,it.Amt,periodFrmDT,PeriodToDT
    from invHeader ih
                inner join customer c on c.custID =ih.custID
                inner join mstUnit mu on mu.unitID=ih.unitID
                inner join invTran it on it.invID=ih.invHeaderID
                inner join billingHeads bh on bh.BillHeadID=it.headID   
               )
```

Comment: thanks for this solution but its not working properly. In Charge1_amt,Charge1_periodFrm,Charge1_periodTo,......Charge3_periodTo columns no value is displaying

Comment: Try again? - I found a mistake.

Comment: Is the data you have provided correct? Because I've double checked my query with that data, and it's running fine.